# How to transform Pandas dataframe for likert scale visualization?

Tags: python, plotly, analysis, survey, likert

I am in the process of analyzing a survey. This contains likert scales. To display them with Plotly (see [link](https://geeksforgeeks.org/diverging-bar-chart-using-python/)), I need an appropriate format. Therefore my question, how do I get from the following format :

[image]

to this target format:

[image]

Source Dataframe:

```
    {
        "ID": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
        "Q1": [
            "no answer",
            "Very satisfied",
            "no answer",
            "no answer",
            "Very satisfied",
            "no answer",
            "no answer",
            "Very satisfied",
            "Very satisfied",
            "no answer",
            "no answer",
            "Neither satisfied nor dissatisfied",
            "no answer",
            "Very satisfied",
            "Neither satisfied nor dissatisfied",
            "Somewhat satisfied",
        ],
        "Q2": [
            "no answer",
            "Very satisfied",
            "no answer",
            "no answer",
            "Very satisfied",
            "no answer",
            "no answer",
            "Very satisfied",
            "Very satisfied",
            "no answer",
            "no answer",
            "Somewhat satisfied",
            "no answer",
            "Very satisfied",
            "Somewhat dissatisfied",
            "Neither satisfied nor dissatisfied",
        ],
        "Q3": [
            "no answer",
            "no answer",
            "no answer",
            "no answer",
            "no answer",
            "no answer",
            "no answer",
            "no answer",
            "no answer",
            "no answer",
            "no answer",
            "no answer",
            "no answer",
            "Neither satisfied nor dissatisfied",
            "no answer",
            "Somewhat satisfied",
        ],
    }
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `ID` is index of `df`, you can do this:

```
pd.concat([df[c].value_counts() for c in df.columns],axis=1).fillna(0)
```

Another option is to melt the `df` long, and use `pd.pivot_table()`

```
pd.pivot_table(pd.melt(df),index="value",columns="variable", aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)
```

Comment: df.columns[0:] instead of df.columns[1:] to have all 3 Q's in the transformed df. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: yes, if `ID` is index; in that case, you can just use `df.columns`